# AngularJs delete record on nested grouped rows

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple page to group record and then add a button to eliminate some records.

The problem is that the record eliminated that has the same name is deleted from the wrong grouped list. And also if a list have no grouped records should disappear, and instead is always there.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/qyb6N/15/

```
// create a deferred object to be resolved later
var teamsDeferred = $q.defer();

// return a promise. The promise says, "I promise that I'll give you your
// data as soon as I have it (which is when I am resolved)".
$scope.teams = teamsDeferred.promise;

// create a list of unique teams
var uniqueTeams = unique($scope.players, 'team');

// resolve the deferred object with the unique teams
// this will trigger an update on the view
teamsDeferred.resolve(uniqueTeams);

// function that takes an array of objects
// and returns an array of unique valued in the object
// array for a given key.
// this really belongs in a service, not the global window scope
function unique(data, key) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i][key];
        if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    console.log(result)
    console.log(Math.ceil(result.length / 10))
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil(result.length / 10);
    return result;
}

$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.pageSize = 5;
$scope.maxSize = 2;

$scope.deleteItem = function(item){
    //code to delete here
    var index=$scope.players.indexOf(item)
    $scope.players.splice(index,1);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the group when nothing is listed, you need to get the filtered list and then use `ng-show` to drive the display. This is a bit tricky:

```
<div ng-show="currentList.length>0" ng-repeat="team in teams| startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*pageSize  | limitTo:pageSize | filter:searchInput"> <b>{{team}}</b>
    <li ng-repeat="player in (currentList = (players | filter: {team: team}))">{{player.name}}
        <button class="btn btn-small" type="button" ng-click="deleteItem(player)">Delete</button>
    </li>
</div>
```

However I am not seeing the problem you said about removing from wrong group. Can you let me know how to reproduce it?

Comment: @Tropicalista OK. No wonder. But hope my answer helps you to solve the display issue then.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with my change follow my approach for now, I can delete the right child (for example the right "George" record), but not be able to hide the grouping row... http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/qyb6N/15/

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with this code: team.length>0 -- http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/qyb6N/17/

Comment: @Tropicalista Is that only place I changed? Look at the 2nd line

Comment: Ops, I need a coffee!!! now it seems great, but another problem will be to update the pagination...I will need to update the pages with the correct number of records...thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of something expanding on the tip from SpykeBytes

```
      <div ng-repeat="location in journey.locations">
                <div id="location_div_{{ $index }}">
                    <label class="journey-label">Location name</label>
                    <input class="journey-input" id="location_{{ $index }}" type="text" ng-model="location.location_name" />
                    <button ng-show="editable" tabindex="-1" class="journey-button remove" ng-click="removeItem(journey.locations, $index)">
                        Remove location
                    </button>
```

Then in my controller I set up an action that takes deletes the individual item

```
$scope.removeItem = function(itemArray, index) {
  return itemArray.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Index won't help you here because the {{$index}} that ng-repeat provides is within the groupings. That is, each grouping restarts the $index variable.  You are going to need a unique identifier for each record though. Without that there is no way to be sure that the record you want to remove is the right one.

As far as the groupings, you can recreate the model whenever you delete something. This wouldn't work with the sample data in the Fiddle, but it works when you're dealing with a real datasource.

Comment: I've tried to recreate the model, here on my local machine with an http request, but when I try the pagination give me a first blank page and other working, if I switch the page also the first page is back again...

Answer (score 0):

You can instead pass the index of the object if it is within ng-repeat.

Comment: Could you be more detailed?